# How to separate local from shared code using git repos

Tags: git, perl

I am developing and maintaining a pile of perl glue code for third party applications running on different servers. Each of the servers currently has a git repo for developing the code running there and a push-to-deploy mechanism to roll changes out to the respective production servers.

While there are generally different scripts running on the different servers, I have now noticed that some perl scripts and modules are useful and necessary on all the servers. I want to pull those out so I have a single place where I can maintain them, while still testing and deploying them in conjunction with the code that is local to each server. Local scripts and modules use shared modules, shared scripts use shared modules, but there's no dependency the other way round.

Current repository structure:

Server 1 ~/usr/dev:

```
localscript1.pl
sharedscript1.pl
perl-modules/localmodule1.pm
perl-modules/sharedmodule1.pm
```

Server 2:

```
localscript2.pl
sharedscript1.pl
perl-modules/localmodule2.pm
perl-modules/sharedmodule1.pm
```

I want to pull out sharedscript1.pl and sharedmodule1.pm into their own repo for source control, but would prefer for all the scripts to end up in the same folder structure in test and production environments.

My current idea for implementing this involves creating a repo for the shared code, and setting this one up as a remote repo for the local repos.

Shared repo:

```
sharedscript1.pl
perl-modules/sharedmodule1.pm
```

I could then define the shared repo as a remote for the local repos and pull commits from there into the local code. After testing and committing there I can use my existing deployment process to push everything to production.

Is this a reasonable setup to use? Any problems/pitfalls with this approach I should be aware of? Is there a better way to handle this case?

Note: I want to keep this fairly lightweight, the final buildout will be three or four local servers, with maybe a dozen scripts and a couple of local modules each. The shared repo would currently have two scripts and one module, with the potential for a few more.

Additional note: I'm running git version 1.6.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Having all files be in the same folder may cause yourself or somebody else difficulty when trying to determine what source each file came from, and accordingly how it should be maintained.

If your dependencies are not reflected somehow in your file structure, then do not be surprised when you or someone else starts adding in localized code and committing to your 'core' repository.

You can still have all files be effectively in the same location, however, by using softlinks to the localized directories.

For example, the following softlink structure would give you flat file structure for usage, but hierarchical file structure for dependencies and modular maintenance.

```
 basedir/perl-modules/localmodule1.pm -> ../../localized-code/server1/perlmodules/localmodule1
 basedir/localscript1.pl -> ../localized-code/server1/scripts/localscript1.pl
```

Using a simple install script, you could just generate all softlinks to the relevant `server1` folder or subfolder when you are installing on a server needing the `server1` code.

To maintain version control, you can `gitignore` all files except the core modules in the base directories, and use git `submodules` to maintain code for each of the localized directories.

That way, you dont need to have all submodules included in all servers.

As a more general potential pitfall, be wary of complicated installation or upgrade processes. Eventually, you are going to install the system on multiple servers. As a potential guidepost for yourself, remember that as per the JOEL test, if you cannot make a build in one step, then your install process is error prone. Test your install process and you will find your own potential issues. If you can run a clean install for all your servers, and still be in a position to do maintenance, then you should be fine!